# $\vdash$ symbol with newtxmath package

Tags: newtx, newtxmath

I'm using the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[noamssymbols]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$ \vdash \nvdash \vDash\nvDash$
\end{document}
```

This is what I got.

[image]

I want the `$\vdash$` symbol look the same as the others. What should I do?

Comment: Remove the `noamssymbols` option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol `\vdash` is not defined by `amssymb` but it is contained in `fontmath.ltx`, so adding the option `noamssymbols` when loading `newtxmath` has no effect on it.

You can add the following lines in your preamble

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{mysymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vdash}{\mathrel}{mysymbols}{96}
```

to achieve what you want:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[noamssymbols]{newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mysymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vdash}{\mathrel}{mysymbols}{96}

\begin{document}
$ \vdash \nvdash \vDash\nvDash$
\end{document}
```

Otherwise, if you want all symbols in NewTX style, simply remove the option `noamssymbols` when loading `newtxmath`, as suggested by egreg.